# Embedding other installers using NSIS

Tags: nsis

I an new to NSIS scripting. I want to create a custom installer which would wrap around another installer(FEKO). This method [Embedding other installers](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Embedding_other_installers) suggested on the NSIS website did not work for me

The script compiles correctly but the embedded application is not installed. Here is the script

```
!include "MUI2.nsh"
!include "logiclib.nsh"

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME 
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"


#Name of the application we are trying to install
Name "FEKO"

# update this section to add 'contact' info
BrandingText "Please contact support at xyz@abc.com for any issues.   "


# define the name of installer
OutFile "Custom_FEKO_6.2_Installer.exe"

# define default installation directory
InstallDir "C:\FEKO\6.2\"

DirText "Choose a directory where you want to install FEKO"


# start default section
Section "FEKO Installation"

    # set the installation directory as the destination for the following actions
    SetOutPath $INSTDIR

    DetailPrint "Extracting FEKO Files into Installation Directory" 

    # specify files to go into the installation directory path
    File /r "C:\Feko_Installer\*"

    # set the current working directory
    SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"      
SectionEnd


Section "FEKO installation" FEKO
    DetailPrint "Installing Feko"

    # run the FEKO installer and wait for it to finish

    File "C:\Feko_Installer\feko_distrib_6.2_win64.exe"
    ExecWait "$INSTDIR\feko_distrib_6.2_win64.exe"

    DetailPrint "Finishing up Installation"
SectionEnd
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If the child installer needs admin privileges you need to put `RequestExecutionLevel admin` in your script. ExecWait (CreateProcess) fails if the exe has a manifest requesting elevation.
2. Correct quoting for ExecWait is: `ExecWait '"c:\full\path\to\app.exe" /param1 "par am 2" /param3'`

Comment: I did the same but it's not working in my case. I've dependent DLL files with exe file too. how can I include those files while custom installing?