# Electron-builder NSIS, embedding other installers

Tags: nsis, electron-builder, nsdialogs

I have created a little electron program for one of my friends, it is a patcher for a private metin2 server of some sort. The game itself is really old so it requires a few redisturables to be installed. 
*[dxwebsetup0411 / dotNetFx35setup / vcredist_x86 ( i believe its a 2013 version) ]*

I want to include them as an option at the end of the install (or even before it, doesn't really matter).
I have found a few examples how to do so but they are all for Standalone NSIS installers and when i try to include that script ( in the build/installer.nsh file ), the build process crashes, presumably because its not the main build script therefor adding Sections is prohibited (?).

Im really new to NSIS scripts and NSIS overall.

So far i only figured out how to put checkboxes and labels and so on in, with the help of nsDialogs, but as i looked at its documentation, it seemed that there are no option where i could do this.

**Any help would be greatly appreciated.**

EDIT :

My script currently is almost empty, I only changed the default directory, but anyway here is that:

```
!macro preInit
  SetRegView 64
  WriteRegExpandStr HKLM "${INSTALL_REGISTRY_KEY}" InstallLocation "C:\Decay2"
  WriteRegExpandStr HKCU "${INSTALL_REGISTRY_KEY}" InstallLocation "C:\Decay2"
  SetRegView 32
  WriteRegExpandStr HKLM "${INSTALL_REGISTRY_KEY}" InstallLocation "C:\Decay2"
  WriteRegExpandStr HKCU "${INSTALL_REGISTRY_KEY}" InstallLocation "C:\Decay2"
!macroend
```

Everything i know about electron-builder's NSIS main script and this included script is here :

- [Custom Script Example](https://www.electron.build/configuration/nsis#custom-nsis-script)
- [NSIS- Electron Builder](https://www.electron.build/configuration/nsis)

Comment: Include the script you have so far here, that will greatly increase your chances of getting an answer. A lot of people who know NSIS could probably help but without seeing the actual script they couldn't more then guess at the problem (which a lot won't do).

Comment: The problem with this, the only thing (that is working) in my script is just overwriting the default install directory. I do not have the mainscript that electron-builder uses.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible to embed other installers and execute them. See this example on SO:
[Embedding other installers using NSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19100826/embedding-other-installers-using-nsis)

or these official NSIS tutorials/guides: https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Embedding_other_installers

Please post your script and build file(s) if you have some issue with your script and you expect specific answer.

Comment: All im doing is running electron-build --win. It has an option for including a script. And i want to embed the installers in that included script, which is empty for now, i used to have a macro that changes the default directory. I will edit my question as soon as i get home and add the remaining information you requested. Atleast i will try.

Comment: Edited the question.